# sound output does not automatically switch to headphones on startup

Tags: sound, kubuntu, headphones

I have a Dell Precision 3450 desktop computer which currently runs Kubuntu 22.04.

When I turn the computer on with the headphones plugged in to the 3.5 mm connector, the sound output is not automatically sent to the headphones, but to the built-in speakers instead. The output switches to the headphones after I unplug and replug the headphones, which I sometimes have to do several times. I have been doing so for a long time, on the same computer with older kubuntu versions, and on previous computers as well if I remember correctly, but recently it has become especially annoying since I often have to unplug and replug several times before getting the sound to the headphones, which gives an annoying crackling sound.

Is this a known problem? Can I somehow fix it with some configuration setting, or is it purely hardware related?